# How to write a finder method that gets the model by the latest date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, finder

Using Rails 5.0.1, I have a table with a Postgres "timestamp without time zone" column.  I would like to get the row that matches the greatest value for this column.  I tried this:

```
@index_value = CryptoIndexValue.first(:order => "index_date desc", :limit => 1)
```

In my controller I am getting this error:

```
ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): "{:order=>\"index_date desc\""):
```

What's the right way to get the row based on the latest value for that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just want to use the `.order` method (see the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)), something like:

```
@index_value = CryptoIndexValue.order(index_date: :desc).first
```